# Defining a protocol to require one method only if another is implemented

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-protocol

I've got a fairly complicated protocol which I'm adding methods to.  Most of the new methods are `@optional`, but they are paired.

For example, these two methods work together:

```
@optional
   - (BOOL) shouldIDoSomethingHere;
   - (CGPoint) whereShouldIDoIt;
```

In this example, if the first method is implemented, I want to declare the second method as `@required`, otherwise both are optional.  What I want is a way to nest or group protocol methods as either all required or not based on context.

Ideally something like:

```
@optional
    @required
    - (BOOL) shouldIDoSomethingHere;
    - (CGPoint) whereShouldIDoIt; 
    @endRequired 
    //... next optional method
```

Comment: Not quite possible. But don't worry too much about this. Check with `respondsToSelector:` at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to enforce this at compile-time. Your best bet is, at runtime, when the your `delegate` property is set (or whatever you use to refer to the object implementing the protocol), just go ahead and implement whatever conformance rules you need there using `-respondsToSelector:` and throw an exception immediately if the object doesn't conform to your rules. Something like:

```
- (void)setDeleate:(id<MyDelegate>)delegate {
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldIDoSomethingHere)]) {
        NSAssert([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(whereShouldIDoIt)], @"Delegate must respond to -whereShouldIDoIt if it responds to -shouldIDoSomethingHere");
    }
    // ...
    _delegate = delegate;
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I had a feeling it wouldn't be simple